# YQL yahooapi works in browser but not cURL

Tags: yql, yahoo-api

Looking for help with the above.

If you use the URI listed below in a browser (Firefox & Chrome) it works; however, if I try it from cURL (or wget) it does not return the same results (to me it does not work). See results below.  I have even tried to use other languages (VBA) and the same result, even tried to duplicate the HTTP headers (using developer tools to capture what is sent).  No luck!  Anyone have ideas ...

URI:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)>&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

cURL returns this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2017-09-17T00:03:06Z" yahoo:lang="en-US"><results><stock symbol="ktos"/></results></query><!-- total: 8 -->
```

Browsers return this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2017-09-17T00:00:44Z" yahoo:lang="en-US"><results><quote symbol="AAPL"><Ask>160.10</Ask><AverageDailyVolume>27056300</AverageDailyVolume><Bid>160.00</Bid><AskRealtime/><BidRealtime/><BookValue>25.61</BookValue><Change_PercentChange>+1.60 - +1.01%</Change_PercentChange><Change>+1.60</Change><Commission/><Currency>USD</Currency><ChangeRealtime/><AfterHoursChangeRealtime/><DividendShare>2.52</DividendShare><LastTradeDate>9/15/2017</LastTradeDate><TradeDate/><EarningsShare>8.81</EarningsShare><ErrorIndicationreturnedforsymbolchangedinvalid/><EPSEstimateCurrentYear>9.01</EPSEstimateCurrentYear><EPSEstimateNextYear>10.95</EPSEstimateNextYear><EPSEstimateNextQuarter>3.84</EPSEstimateNextQuarter><DaysLow>158.00</DaysLow><DaysHigh>160.97</DaysHigh><YearLow>104.08</YearLow><YearHigh>164.94</YearHigh><HoldingsGainPercent/><AnnualizedGain/><HoldingsGain/><HoldingsGainPercentRealtime/><HoldingsGainRealtime/><MoreInfo/><OrderBookRealtime/><MarketCapitalization>825.82B</MarketCapitalization><MarketCapRealtime/><EBITDA>70.21B</EBITDA><ChangeFromYearLow>55.80</ChangeFromYearLow><PercentChangeFromYearLow>+53.61%</PercentChangeFromYearLow><LastTradeRealtimeWithTime/><ChangePercentRealtime/><ChangeFromYearHigh>-5.06</ChangeFromYearHigh><PercebtChangeFromYearHigh>-3.07%</PercebtChangeFromYearHigh><LastTradeWithTime>4:00pm - &lt;b&gt;159.88&lt;/b&gt;</LastTradeWithTime><LastTradePriceOnly>159.88</LastTradePriceOnly><HighLimit/><LowLimit/><DaysRange>158.00 - 160.97</DaysRange><DaysRangeRealtime/><FiftydayMovingAverage>158.97</FiftydayMovingAverage><TwoHundreddayMovingAverage>149.42</TwoHundreddayMovingAverage><ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage>10.46</ChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage><PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage>+7.00%</PercentChangeFromTwoHundreddayMovingAverage><ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage>0.91</ChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage><PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage>+0.57%</PercentChangeFromFiftydayMovingAverage><Name>Apple Inc.</Name><Notes/><Open>158.47</Open><PreviousClose>158.28</PreviousClose><PricePaid/><ChangeinPercent>+1.01%</ChangeinPercent><PriceSales>3.66</PriceSales><PriceBook>6.18</PriceBook><ExDividendDate>8/10/2017</ExDividendDate><PERatio>18.15</PERatio><DividendPayDate>8/17/2017</DividendPayDate><PERatioRealtime/><PEGRatio>1.45</PEGRatio><PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear>17.74</PriceEPSEstimateCurrentYear><PriceEPSEstimateNextYear>14.60</PriceEPSEstimateNextYear><Symbol>AAPL</Symbol><SharesOwned/><ShortRatio>1.90</ShortRatio><LastTradeTime>4:00pm</LastTradeTime><TickerTrend/><OneyrTargetPrice>172.35</OneyrTargetPrice><Volume>49114602</Volume><HoldingsValue/><HoldingsValueRealtime/><YearRange>104.08 - 164.94</YearRange><DaysValueChange/><DaysValueChangeRealtime/><StockExchange>NMS</StockExchange><DividendYield>1.59</DividendYield><PercentChange>+1.01%</PercentChange></quote></results></query><!-- total: 17 -->
```

Comment: It seems that I got it to work by replacing the forward slashes and colons with the encoded values %3A and %2F.  Go figure ...